# when mouse hover hide img and show img

Tags: html, css

I want to ask question please ( if I'have img code like )

```
<img src"img1.png" id="img1" />
```

and  I'have another img

```
<img src="img1.png" id="img2" />
```

how to : when mouse hover hide img1 and show img2 in place

```
#img2{display:none;} /*to hide img2*/
#img1:hover{display:none;} /*to hide when hover*/
#img2:hover{display:block;} /*to show the img 2 */
```

that code is not working : I want to replace img1 when mouse hover to img2

Comment: write image extension pls...like img1.jpg/gif/png

Comment: Done Image Extension

Comment: can you please send image links pls or jsfiddle link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8pyemtju/)

You should change your CSS a little bit as follows

```
#img2 {
  display: none;
}

#img1:hover{
  display: none;
}

#img1:hover~#img2 {
  display: block;
}
```

You can use the `~` selector to achieve this.

Comment: thanx :)  this ~ like To ? 

img hover to img2 :) < thanx ^_^ I'understand now

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```css
#img1, #img2 {
  position: absolute;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

#img2:hover {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/400/400" alt="Smiley face" id="img1" width="42" height="42">
<img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/200/200" alt="Smiley face" id="img2" width="42" height="42">
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one much cooler example and one of what you asked for:

```
<div class="reveal">
<img src="http://c.wrzuta.pl/wi16455/94df8de30009b2384fe15089" 
width=280px height=280px>
<img class="img2"   src="http://static.gamespot.com/uploads/
original/1123/11234696/2517081-0135811689-yamah.jpg"
width=280px  height=280px>
<div class="activator" ></div>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/GopoJB